# How to have multi website with loadbalancer cisco (apache)

Tags: apache-2.2, cisco, load-balancing

I have two servers (linux with apache 2). I have a load balancer cisco ace which redirect all requests on server 1 or server 2.

I need 2 websites:

- www.sites1.com
- www.sites2.com

In both server, I added virtualhost in `httpd.conf` but It doesn't work.

Special configuration in loadbalancer?
Special configuration in apache?

Pour récapituler:
www.sites1.com -> load balancer -> server 1 or 2 -> virutalhost website for sites1
www.sites2.com -> load balancer -> server 1 or 2 -> virutalhost site ndd2

Comment: not sure if this is what you are after, see if [my question here regaring to vhosts](http://serverfault.com/questions/197463/need-assistance-in-regards-to-wamp-virtual-hosts) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to log the requests coming from your load balancer (is layer 4 or layer 7 load balancing?); especially log the HTTP_HOST header and see if the host www.sitesX.com are set.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I discover that I have virtual bay (LB + server 1 + server 2) and I used bad address.